# Android - Killing a child in firebase database kills my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I'm storing a list of data for each user with this `ConnectionInformation.java`.

```
package trickandroid.fulllogin;

/**
 * Created by Simon Peter on 19-May-17.
 */

public class ConnectionInformation {

    String due, selectArea, connectionNum, doorNum, conName, phoneNum, aadharNum, rationNum;

    public  ConnectionInformation(){

    }

    public ConnectionInformation(String due, String selectArea, String connectionNum, String doorNum, String conName, String phoneNum, String aadharNum, String rationNum) {
        this.connectionNum = connectionNum;
        this.doorNum = doorNum;
        this.conName = conName;
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
        this.aadharNum = aadharNum;
        this.rationNum = rationNum;
        this.selectArea = selectArea;
        this.due = due;
    }

    public String getDue() {
        return due;
    }

    public void setDue(String due) {
        this.due = due;
    }

    public String getSelectArea() {
        return selectArea;
    }

    public void setSelectArea(String selectArea) {
        this.selectArea = selectArea;
    }

    public String getConnectionNum() {
        return connectionNum;
    }

    public void setConnectionNum(String connectionNum) {
        this.connectionNum = connectionNum;
    }

    public String getDoorNum() {
        return doorNum;
    }

    public void setDoorNum(String doorNum) {
        this.doorNum = doorNum;
    }

    public String getConName() {
        return conName;
    }

    public void setConName(String conName) {
        this.conName = conName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNum() {
        return phoneNum;
    }

    public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum) {
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }

    public String getAadharNum() {
        return aadharNum;
    }

    public void setAadharNum(String aadharNum) {
        this.aadharNum = aadharNum;
    }

    public String getRationNum() {
        return rationNum;
    }

    public void setRationNum(String rationNum) {
        this.rationNum = rationNum;
    }
}
```

Adding data to the firebase works very fine. This is my database structure.
[image]

This is my `showData()` method where `.getDoorNum()` is called to display it on the ListView.

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (expandableListView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ConnectionInformation cInfo = new ConnectionInformation();
                cInfo.setDoorNum(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).getValue(ConnectionInformation.class).getDoorNum());
                cInfo.setPhoneNum(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).getValue(ConnectionInformation.class).getPhoneNum());
                cInfo.setAadharNum(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).getValue(ConnectionInformation.class).getAadharNum());
                cInfo.setRationNum(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).getValue(ConnectionInformation.class).getRationNum());

                ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
                users.add(cInfo.getDoorNum());
                users.add(cInfo.getPhoneNum());
                users.add(cInfo.getAadharNum());
                users.add(cInfo.getRationNum());

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users);
                expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this code for deleting the child.

```
disBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mdata.child(oldArea).child(key).removeValue();
                connection.child(oldArea).child(key).removeValue();
                toast("Connection Number " + oldNum + " Disconnected Successfully");
                startActivity(new Intent(DisconnectActivity.this,AreaGridActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

The code works fine in the database but my app crashes with this error...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String trickandroid.fulllogin.ConnectionInformation.getDoorNum()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at trickandroid.fulllogin.DetailsActivity.showData(DetailsActivity.java:449)
                                                                          at trickandroid.fulllogin.DetailsActivity.access$100(DetailsActivity.java:33)
                                                                          at trickandroid.fulllogin.DetailsActivity$3.onDataChange(DetailsActivity.java:129)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

https://gist.github.com/SimonPeter1909/d70be328dd6d9b099a8a96454922432f[DetailsActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/SimonPeter1909/d70be328dd6d9b099a8a96454922432f)

I have tried many ways but I can't pass the error...

Comment: nobody should kill any children.

Comment: ;)... But I'm not killing any real child.

Comment: Firstly, I completely agree with @Blundell but secondly I think you need to add more to your question. What is happening in your EventListener(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation here is that you have a `ValueEventListener` which is triggered once when the listener is added, and then again any time the data changes. The listener is explicitly expecting to find an entry with a certain `areaName` and `key`.

This is fine the first time the listener runs, but then on button click you delete the entry with that `areaName` and `key`. This triggers the listener again(you changed the data), the listener tries to do something with the entry at that `areaName` and `key`, it doesn't exist, you get a `NullPointerException`.

There are a number of ways to avoid this, but you probably need to rethink the flow and exactly what you want to happen.

A quick fix here could be to try checking if the entry is there before trying to use it:

```
if(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).exists()) {
    ConnectionInformation cInfo = new ConnectionInformation();
    cInfo.setDoorNum(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).getValue(ConnectionInformation.class).getDoorNum());
    cInfo.setPhoneNum(ds.child(userID).child("Connection Detail").child(areaName).child(key).getValue(ConnectionInformation.class).getPhoneNum());
...
...
} else {
//that entry doesn't exist, do something else
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you very much. with the crystal clear explanation, u solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

not enough info, but i think you are callig getDoorNum, when there is no string in there . try

```
if (!yourmodelclassobject.getDoorNum()==null)
{
//then print your value or whatever is that you do}
```

or please post little more info

Comment: Can you please specify the info u required?... :)

Comment: your DetailsActivity.class, where getDoorNum() is called.

Comment: DetailsActivity has many lines. So I have posted `showData()` method... please check my question.

Comment: after you declare the array list implement null checks before adding the values to array  if(!cInfo.getDoorNum==null){users.add(cInfo.getDoorNum)}

Comment: exception is obvious it is model class a null

Comment: But `(!cInfo.getDoorNum==null)` throws an error stating operator ! cannot applied to java....